# Do “functions” always refer to “wavefunctions” in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

For example, what do we mean when we say that “Operator acts on the function that follows it”? What are the examples of “functions” that operators act on (in quantum mechanics)?

Comment: Yes, in that sentence, the "function" in reference will always be a wave function

Comment: These are general statements about operators and functions. In quantum mechanics the operators represent physical quantities and act on the wave functions.